# UIButton adjusting after build storyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uipopovercontroller, cgrect

I have set up a vc that will be called as a modal when an action is executed. But when the vc pops up the positions of the buttons adjusts. How do I set the positions?

I have this on my viewdidload. It doesn't seem to work.

```
btnObjectRole1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

This is what it looks like

This is before being simulated:

[image]

This is after

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the buttons are being positioned by their autolayout *constraints* from the nib. Setting the frame will have no effect against that; the constraints will win sooner or later.

So you need to learn to read and adjust the constraints in the nib so that the buttons do what you want when the view is resized smaller to act as a form-style presented view.

Comment: so do i have to turn off auto layout then?

Comment: You could. But better, I think, to learn to *use* the constraints in the nib. Autolayout is really great! Here's where my book explains about them: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_constraints_in_the_nib